# Converting nested list of tuples to nested list of first element from tuples

Tags: python, list, nested

I have a nested list like this one:

```
a = [([('m', 2), ([('o', 1), ([('k', 1), ('h', 1)], 2)], 3)], 5),
     ([('e', 3), ([([('t', 1), ('a', 1)], 2), (' ', 2)], 4)], 7)]
```

I'd like to get rid of the second element in every tuple, so the list becomes a list of chars only. Like that:

```
[['m', ['o', ['k', 'h']]], ['e', [['t', 'a'], ' ']]]
```

I've tried the following:

```
def transform(array):
    for x in array:
        if type(x[0]) is list:
            transform(x[0])
        else:
            x = x[0]
```

It turns tuples to chars, but it doesn't affect the given array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a recursive list comprehension:

```
def recursive_strip(my_list):
    """Recursively remove the second element from nested lists of tuples."""
    return [
        recursive_strip(one) if isinstance(one, list) else one
        for one, two in my_list
    ]
```

Running this code on the example provided we get:

```
a = [([('m', 2), ([('o', 1), ([('k', 1), ('h', 1)], 2)], 3)], 5),
     ([('e', 3), ([([('t', 1), ('a', 1)], 2), (' ', 2)], 4)], 7)]

result = recursive_strip(a)
```

With `result` being:

```
[['m', ['o', ['k', 'h']]], ['e', [['t', 'a'], ' ']]]
```